# 1D numpy concatenate: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to store numpy array into to another numpy array

I am using `np.concatenate`

This is my code

```
x=np.concatenate(x,s_x)
```

These are the type and the shape of `x and s_x`

```
Type of s_x: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, Shape of s_x: (173,)
Type of x: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (0,), Shape of x: (0,)
```

This is the error being displayed

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You need to pass the arrays as an iterable (a tuple or list), thus the correct syntax is

```
x=np.concatenate((x, s_x))
```

Comment: For such a common and useful function it really does have the most useless error messages. Thanks!

Comment: Python is great, but it's this kind of nitpicking that makes it a pain in the neck sometimes.

Comment: I am lucky to scroll down the google search results enough and find this answer.

Comment: @UlissesBraga-Neto problem is not with Python but rather with numpy. The error message should be more informative.