# 'numpy.concatenate' produces error: "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am self-answering the following question as when I made the following mistake, I couldn't find an answer.

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

np.concatenate(a, b)
```

Produces the following error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Also a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47388013/2988730

Answer (score -1):

The arrays to be concatenated need to be wrapped in parentheses:

```py
np.concatenate((a, b))
>>> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```